# Can a method reference a method in the same class if that method references the original method

Tags: java, methods, reference

I am making a simple text-based game. I have a method in my class which references another method in the same class, but that method references the method referencing it if a certain condition is met.

So basically if the character chooses to open the menu, the Character.mainMenu() method is called, and that references Character.invMenu() or Character.statsMenu() depending on what is selected.

If the user instead chooses to select Back from the mainMenu(), another method called backSetter() is called. This method takes the current x and y coordinates and returns a location ID, to return the user to whatever location they opened the menu in.

Inside the sub-menu methods (the methods called by the mainMenu() method) such as invMenu(), there are also options to go back: 1. Back and 2. Home. The Back option returns the user to the main menu, which calls the mainMenu() method. And the Home option returns the user to the location they opened the menu in, calling the backSetter() method. The problem however, is if I call these methods from the invMenu() method, they don't seem to do anything and my program freezes.

Here is the basic template of my Character class (other classes referenced here are MainClass which contains the setLocation() method and the GameText class which references the gameText() method).

```
class Character{

    static Scanner userInput = new Scanner();
    static String choice;
    static int backChoice = 0;

    public static void backSetter(){
        if (xAxis == 0 && yAxis == 0){
            backChoice = MainClass.setLocation(0,0);
            GameText.gameText(backChoice);
        }else if (xAxis == 0 && yAxis == 1){
            .....
        }
    }

    public static void mainMenu(){
        //My menu options: 1. Inventory, 2. Stats, etc... 5. BACK <- important
        choice = userInput.next();

        if (choice.equals("1")){
            invMenu();
        }else if (choice.equals("5")){
            backSetter();
    }

    public static void invMenu(){
        // Determines current items in inventory and prints them out
        //My menu options: 1. Back, 2. Home <- where the problem happens
        choice = userInput.next();

        if (choice.equals("1")){
            mainMenu();
        }else if (choice.equals("2")){
            backSetter();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is perfectly legal and will compile. It is called "indirect recursion". You must be *very* careful that there is some way to get out of the recursion, though. In other words, you can easily be caught in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is legal - this is what it means for methods to be [recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion).  Make sure that you don't have a case of infinite recursion, i.e. make sure that your methods eventually stop calling each other - if the recursion eventually terminates then you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is pretty much an example of recursion. It won't create any errors.
But, because it's recursive, it may cause an infinite loop if their is no way of getting to a base case state.
In a case like this where methods call each other and the recursion isn't evident at first glance, an infinite loop is a lot more likely.

It might not be a bad idea to somehow isolate that recursion so it is a lot more evident, making the code cleaner, and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is legal, however it is pretty bad design.  Recursive menu calls can get you into some trouble.  I feel as though a return would be better, however I don't know the context of this code.

```
public static void invMenu(){
    // Determines current items in inventory and prints them out
    //My menu options: 1. Back, 2. Home <- where the problem happens
    choice = userInput.next();

    if (choice.equals("1")){
       return;
    }else if (choice.equals("2")){
        backSetter();
    }
}
```

If you were to go about doing this, you would need to adjust the code of the main menu to handle the return (i.e. a loop of some sort).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, I thought it might be causing an infinite loop. And yes, without the full code it's hard to spot where I'm going wrong. I wanted to add this as a comment but it was too many characters so I've added it as a an answer.

I've been looking at my methods and I can't see how it gets stuck in an infinite loop. Method1 which calls Method2, has to take user input before determining what to do. So if Methpd1 calls Method2, which calls Method1 again, why does it get stuck, since the user has an option of going back to the normal game in either method. Here are my methods, maybe seeing it fully can shed some light on where I'm going wrong.

The FantasyGameText.gameText method just takes the locID and outputs that location's dialogue options. The FantasyGameText.setLocation method is the actual method which sets the location ID, the backSetter method simply combines it with the gameText method (Basically the same way I start my game, xAxis = 0, yAxis = 0, so locId = 0, which is the starting portion of my game).

```
public static void backSetter(){
    if (xAxis == 2 && yAxis == 1){
        backChoice = setLocation(2, 1);
        FantasyGameText.gameText(backChoice);
    }else if (xAxis == 4 && yAxis == 1){
        backChoice = setLocation(4, 1);
        FantasyGameText.gameText(backChoice);
    }else if (xAxis == 2 && yAxis == 2){
        backChoice = setLocation(2, 2);
        FantasyGameText.gameText(backChoice);
    }else if (xAxis == 3 && yAxis == 2){
        backChoice = setLocation(3, 3);
        FantasyGameText.gameText(backChoice);
    }else if (xAxis == 4 && yAxis == 2){
        backChoice = setLocation(4, 2);
        FantasyGameText.gameText(backChoice);
    }else if (xAxis == 5 && yAxis == 2){
        backChoice = setLocation(5, 2);
        FantasyGameText.gameText(backChoice);
    }else if (xAxis == 1 && yAxis == 3){
        backChoice = setLocation(1, 3);
        FantasyGameText.gameText(backChoice);
    }else if (xAxis == 2 && yAxis == 3){
        backChoice = setLocation(2, 3);
        FantasyGameText.gameText(backChoice);
    }else if (xAxis == 3 && yAxis == 3){
        backChoice = setLocation(3, 3);
        FantasyGameText.gameText(backChoice);
    }else if (xAxis == 4 && yAxis == 3){
        backChoice = setLocation(4, 3);
        FantasyGameText.gameText(backChoice);
    }else if (xAxis == 2 && yAxis == 4){
        backChoice = setLocation(2, 4);
        FantasyGameText.gameText(backChoice);
    }else if (xAxis == 3 && yAxis == 4){
        backChoice = setLocation(3, 4);
        FantasyGameText.gameText(backChoice);
    }else if (xAxis == 4 && yAxis == 4){
        backChoice = setLocation(4, 4);
        FantasyGameText.gameText(backChoice);
    }else if (xAxis == 5 && yAxis == 4){
        backChoice = setLocation(5, 4);
        FantasyGameText.gameText(backChoice);
    }else if (xAxis == 3 && yAxis == 5){
        backChoice = setLocation(3, 5);
        FantasyGameText.gameText(backChoice);
    }else if (xAxis == 4 && yAxis == 5){
        backChoice = setLocation (4, 5);
        FantasyGameText.gameText(backChoice);
    }else if (xAxis == 30 && yAxis == 30){
        backChoice = setLocation(30, 30);
        FantasyGameText.gameText(backChoice);
    }else if (xAxis == 31 && yAxis == 31){
        backChoice = setLocation(31, 31);
        FantasyGameText.gameText(backChoice);
    }else if (xAxis == 50 && yAxis == 50){
        backChoice = setLocation(50, 50);
        FantasyGameText.gameText(backChoice);
    }else if (xAxis == 51 && yAxis == 51){
        backChoice = setLocation(51, 51);
        FantasyGameText.gameText(backChoice);
    }else if (xAxis == 52 && yAxis == 52){
        backChoice = setLocation(52, 52);
        FantasyGameText.gameText(backChoice);
    }else if (xAxis == 53 && yAxis == 53){
        backChoice = setLocation(53, 53);
        FantasyGameText.gameText(backChoice);
    }else if (xAxis == 54 && yAxis == 54){
        backChoice = setLocation(54, 54);
        FantasyGameText.gameText(backChoice);
    }else if (xAxis == 55 & yAxis == 55){
        backChoice = setLocation(55, 55);
        FantasyGameText.gameText(backChoice);
    }else{
        FantasyGameText.gameText(100);
    }
}

public static void menuHome(){
    boolean correctAnswer = false;
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("-------- CHARACTER --------");
    System.out.println("1. Inventory");
    System.out.println("2. Equip");
    System.out.println("3. Stats");
    System.out.println("4. Quests");
    System.out.println("5. Back");
    while (correctAnswer == false){
        menuChoice = userInput.next();
        System.out.println("");
        if (menuChoice.equals("1") || menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("inventory") || menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("inv")){
            correctAnswer = true;
            invMenu();
        }else if (menuChoice.equals("2") || menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("equip")){
            correctAnswer = true;
            equipMenu();
        }else if (menuChoice.equals("3") || menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("stats") || menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("statistics")){
            correctAnswer = true;
            statsMenu();
        }else if (menuChoice.equals("4") || menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("quests") || menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("quest")){
            correctAnswer = true;
            questMenu();
        }else if (menuChoice.equals("5") || menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("back") || menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("home")){
            correctAnswer = true;
            backSetter();
        }else{
            System.out.println("That is not a valid option, choose again,");
            menuChoice = userInput.next();
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
return;
}

public static void invMenu(){
    boolean correctAnswer = false;
    int invList[] = new int[50];
    int itemAmount[] = new int[50];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
        if (healthPotionAmount > 0){
            invList[0] = 1;
            itemTempName[0] = "Health Potion x ";
            itemAmount[0] = healthPotionAmount;
        }else{
            invList[0] = 0;
        }
        if (rustySwordAmount > 0){
            invList[1] = 1;
            itemTempName[1] = "Rusty Sword x ";
            itemAmount[1] = rustySwordAmount;
        }else{
            invList[1] = 0;
        }
        if (ragsBodyAmount > 0){
            invList[2] = 1;
            itemTempName[2] = "Rags x ";
            itemAmount[2] = ragsBodyAmount;
        }else{
            invList[2] = 0;
        }
        if (chainBodyAmount > 0){
            invList[3] = 1;
            itemTempName[3] = "Chainmail Armor x ";
            itemAmount[3] = chainBodyAmount;
        }else{
            invList[3] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
        if (invList[i] > 0){
            System.out.println(itemTempName[i] + itemAmount[i]);
        }else if (invList[0] == 0 && invList[1] == 0 && invList[2] == 0 && invList[3] == 0){
            System.out.println("You have no items.");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("1. Back");
    System.out.println("2. Home");
    menuChoice = userInput.next();
    System.out.println("");
    while (correctAnswer == false);
    if (menuChoice.equals("1") || menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("back") || menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("b")){
        correctAnswer = true;
        menuHome();
    }else if (menuChoice.equals("2") || menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("home") || menuChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("h")){
        correctAnswer = true;
        backSetter();
    }else{
        System.out.println("That is not a valid option, choose again.");
        menuChoice = userInput.next();
        System.out.println(""); 
    }
}
```